# Capture referring URL parameters w/ Javascript & Pass to Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, referrer, query-string

New to javascript. I'm trying to capture the referring url for a goal page, which has some query parameters structured like so:

example.com/vehicle/?stock=12345

Once I get the query parameters, I want to pass them into Google Analytics using the _gaq.push method. I dont' expect anyone to have the gaq.push method memorized, but is my code structured correctly?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var vehicleURL=document.referrer;
  var stock=vehicleURL.substring(vehicleURL.indexOf('?')+7, vehicleURL.length);

  _gaq.push(['track_Event', 'Leads', 'Vehicle', stock]);
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track:

```
var vehicleURL="example.com/vehicle/?stock=12345";
var stock=vehicleURL.substring(vehicleURL.indexOf('?')+7, vehicleURL.length);

alert(stock); //(12345)

_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Leads', 'Vehicle', stock]);
```

Keep in mind that Google Analytics has little tolerance for error so make sure that _gaq.push is spot on.

Comment: Thanks Jen! Figured out that Wordpress was wrapping my script in paragraph tags so it wasn't working. All fixed now :)

Comment: That's great, glad you have it worked out. But, I believe I answered you're question as posted. Please accept the answer. Thank you.